# 4 bytes string vs 4 bytes integer readed as a string

Tags: c, string, pointers, memory-management

Is it true that reading string that consists of 4 characters including null-terminator, declared as an array/pointer will be readed slower (byte by byte?) than integer value, readed as a string like so:

```
static int val = 'C' + '+' * 256 + '+' * 256 * 256;
printf("%s", (char*)val);
```

Answer (score 0):

The good answer is **DON'T DO THIS!**

The complete answer is: if your processor uses little endian byte ordering (eg: Intel architecture) and int is at least 32 bits, the following amended version of your code will produce the expected output:

```
static int val = 'C' + '+' * 256 + '+' * 256 * 256;
printf("%s\n", (char*)&val);
```

outputs this line on stdout:

```
C++
```

because the byte representation of `0x2b2b43` in memory is `0x43 0x2b 0x2b 0x00`.
The address of val points to same bytes as the character array `"C++"`.  The cast does not change the address but prevents a compiler warning.

Comment: Oh yes. I forgot about the reference. But you didn´t actually answer to the question which is - is it faster?

Comment: Also why shouldn´t I do this?

Comment: @AlanSalios It's not particularly readable or maintainable. As for speed, measure it on your system, with whatever compiler and data you are using.

Comment: How? By setting up a timer?

Comment: `val` is a static variable.  it's value is computed at compile time. There should be no difference with the correct code that uses `static char val[] = "C++";`  and `printf("%s\n", val);`

Comment: @AlanSalios I should point out that your code also exhibits implementation defined behaviour (see C99 `6.3.2.3`), so it's not portable - another reason not to do it.
You can time it using a profiling tool like gprof or similar, or by setting up a loop and timer for each approach.

Comment: You should not use tricks like this because they are not portable, not readable, misleading, useless... Performance would be a bad excuse.  If on the other hand you are trying to lose the casual code reader, there are countless tricks you can play that are more effective.

Comment: @chqrlie Oh well.. I was just curious. Not really going to use this in a sale-alike application. Also name one effective trick?

Comment: @AlanSalios Out of curiosity, I timed 10M iterations of each way, compiled with both clang and gcc, with and without optimisations, and the results were pretty much the same for char array vs. integer cast to char*, except that gcc with no optimisations produces _slower_ code for the cast version (by about 60%), although we are talking utterly negligible time per printf. YMMV. Don't bother with this. If you want obfuscation, check out the IOCCC and [this page](https://www.cise.ufl.edu/~manuel/obfuscate/obfuscate.html)

Comment: Carefully choose variable names: `int O = 1;  if (strcmp(str, "done") == O) ... `.  Similarly `l` can be confused with `I` and `1` depending on the font.  The comma operator can be used to fool the reader too.

Comment: Ahh I see.. I will make tries and see what I will come up with.